# Python removing items from list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a list in the given format:

```
[['John', 'Smith'], ['Linus', 'Torvalds'], ['Bart', 'Simpson']]
```

There are some elements like this in the list ['Linus Torvalds', ''] and I want to remove those. So why doesn't the following code remove them?

```
for i in people:
    if(i[0] == '' or i[1] == ''):
        print people.pop(people.index(i))
```

Comment: I've also tried people.remove(i)

Comment: The list you gave doesn't have any cases where either the first or second element is an empty string.

Comment: When you want to deal with the index as well, use something like `for i, (first, last) in enumerate(people):` and `i` will be 0, 1, 2, ...

Comment: It's quite possible to do what you're trying to do with getting the iterator (`iter(people)`) and calling `iterator.next()` only some of the time... but that's rarely the best solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are changing the list while iterating over it and this is the source of your problems. An approach that works is

```
people[:] = [p for p in people if p[0] != '' and p[1] != '']
```

this way a new temporary list containing only the elements you want is built and then assigned to the original list object when the operation is complete.

Comment: if you want to end up with the same *list object*, you can replace the assignment with `people[:] = [p for p in ...`,  that way, the result of the list comprehension gets stuffed back into the original list.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Good point. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hmmm.  now nobody can see the old way, when you don't need to preserve the list object identity, you can replace the assignment with just `people = [p for p in ...`, which is going to be a bit faster since it avoids some (but not terribly much) copying.

Comment: The original code was trying to change the object in place, using `pop`, possibly because others have an access to it; the current version is therefore a better answer to the original question from a semantic point of view.

Comment: It may be closer to his original solution, but that doesn't mean it's the best solution for any problem that is similar to the question, even for this particular poster.  A successful pythonista can use both techniques.

Answer (score 4):

Or even `people[:] = [p for p in people if all(p)]` if you want to resize the list "in place".

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying the list's length while iterating over it. That causes you to skip values. When you pop one item off the list, here's what happens ([stealing from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list/6260097#6260097)):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...]
 ^
```

That's the state of the list initially; now say 1 is removed and the loop goes to the second item in the list:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6...]
    ^
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to remove things from a list as you iterate over it. So, try one of these instead (Also, I think your condition is not what you want it to be - I've fixed it):

```
L = [['John', 'Smith'], ['Linus', 'Torvalds'], ['Bart', 'Simpson']]
delete_these = []
for index, i in enumerate(L):
    if not i[-1].strip():
        delete_these.append(i)
for i in delete_these:
    L.pop(i)
    delete_these = map(lambda x: x-1, delete_these)
```

OR

```
L = [i for i in L if i[-1].strip()]
```

OR

```
answer = []
for i in L:
    if i[-1].strip():
        answer.append(i)
```

OR

```
i = 0
while i < len(L):
    if not L[i][-1].strip():
        L.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Hope this helps